# NSDate representation in generated SQLite database?

Tags: dbaccess

I am using NSDate for date/time representation in DBAccess framework. However, when I run SQL queries like

```
select date(start) from actions
```

I got strange date instead of my date. Even DBAccess queries doesn't work, like:

`DBResultSet *today = [[[Actions query] where:@"date(end) = date('now')"] fetch];`

In SQLite the column type is correct - timestamp. So that is there any way how to work correctly with dates / times?

Thanks,

Jindrich

Comment: Show the actual and expected date values and please tag your question correctly.

Comment: @sarsonj, Did the answer below help in any way?  Are you still suffering problems?

Comment: @Adrian_H I used another approach, see below. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended with using sqlite functions, instead of converting NSDate, as @Adrian_H suggests. My code for today items looks like:

```
DBResultSet *today = [[[[Actions query] where:@"date(datetime(end, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) = date('now')"] orderByDescending:@"id"] fetch];
```

This results items, where end value is today.

Answer (score 0):

NSDate's are stored as EPOCH, and any NSDate object is converted when in place as a parameter.

So your query would become:

```
DBResultSet *today = [[[Actions query] whereWithFormat:@"end = %@", [NSDate date]] fetch];
```

Obviously, that won't work unless you stored and trimmed the seconds off the date for persistence or retrieval.

It would need to become:

```
DBResultSet *today = [[[Actions query] whereWithFormat:@"end >= %@ AND end <= %@", beginingOfDay, endOfDay] fetch];
```

We could add an internal function to SQLite to help support these better, any suggestions would be welcome.  It might be best to just overload the existing functions.

If you wanted to always store an NSDate without the seconds precision, you could always add something in the entityWillInsert method and create an extension to NSDate to give you the beginning of the day,

```
- (BOOL)entityWillInsert {
  self.end = [self.end dateTrimmedToStartOfDay];
  return YES;
}
```

That might be an easier way to keep all the code simple.

Thanks
Adrian